# Получение ссылки на локальный файл

Tags: php, html

Как реализовать такую фичу, что бы можно было при нажатии на кнопку выбрать файл или лучше файлы на компьютере, и ссылки на эти локальные файлы добавились в строку. Пример как на фото.

Заранее спасибо!



[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я с сайтами не работаю но когда то делал подобное помнится мне для этого есть куча jQuery библиотек вот к примеру демка: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
Вот ссылка на эту библиотеку: https://plugins.jquery.com/blueimp-file-upload-jquery-ui/

Comment: Спасибо, но я ищу решение на html/php.

Comment: Php работает на сервере. Чтобы так сделать нужно отправить форму с именем файла на сервер, там получить путь и вернуть его уже на новой странице. Только к  чему такая тягомотина, когда это можно сделать на клиенте гораздо быстрее с помощью js?